# What should I study before read Analysis on Manifolds written by Munkres?

Tags: analysis

Is Rudin's PMA enough before studying analysis on manifolds? Please let me know if there is more. I'd like to know if I can understand the book before buy it.

Comment: Yeah I did that with a similar background (one intro level real analysis class).

Comment: I highly recommend reading Pugh's Mathematical Analysis for an introductory course to mathematical analysis instead of Walter Rudin's.

Comment: @stressedout I've already studied Rudin's PMA but thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Munkres have answered your question in the [preface](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9tJMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&dq=%22As+indicated,+we+assume+the+reader+has+completed+a+one-term+course+in+analysis+that+included+a+study+of+metric+spaces+and+of+functions+of+a+single+variable.+We+also+assume+the+reader+has+some+background+in+linear+algebra,+including+vector+spaces+and+linear+transformations,+matrix+algebra,+and+determinants.%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT5MjG37vgAhWvGrkGHbFQD68Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22As%20indicated%2C%20we%20assume%20the%20reader%20has%20completed%20a%20one-term%20course%20in%20analysis%20that%20included%20a%20study%20of%20metric%20spaces%20and%20of%20functions%20of%20a%20single%20variable.%20We%20also%20assume%20the%20reader%20has%20some%20background%20in%20linear%20algebra%2C%20including%20vector%20spaces%20and%20linear%20transformations%2C%20matrix%20algebra%2C%20and%20determinants.%22&f=false).

Note that he have mentioned Rudin (among others) in [second paragraph](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9tJMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&dq=%22There+are+a++number+of+excellent+texts+for+such+a+course,+including+books+by+Apostol+%5BA%5D,++Rudin+%5BRu%5D,+Goldberg+%5BGo%5D,+and+Royden+%5BRo%5D,+among+others.%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpoeaO4LvgAhVYIrkGHcgbDlwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22There%20are%20a%20%20number%20of%20excellent%20texts%20for%20such%20a%20course%2C%20including%20books%20by%20Apostol%20%5BA%5D%2C%20%20Rudin%20%5BRu%5D%2C%20Goldberg%20%5BGo%5D%2C%20and%20Royden%20%5BRo%5D%2C%20among%20others.%22&f=false) as a good source for a first course.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I can read preface on the internet.

Comment: @YunYJ You are welcome. Sometimes we can because some parts of some books are available at [Google books](https://books.google.com).